# MS Access Match from Range between two columns

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have table T1 as below

```
RL  OR  FVALU   TVALU
R1  O1  3291    
R1  O1  3002    
R1  O1  3010
R2  O1  2000
```

and Another Table T2 as below:

```
RL  OR  FVALU   TVALU
R1  O1  3291    
R1  O1  3000    3005
R1  O1  5000    
R2  O1  *
```

Expected output should be as below:

```
RL  OR  FVALU   TVALU   MATCHORDOESNOT
R1  O1  3291            MATCH
R1  O1  3002            MATCH
R1  O1  3010            DONOTMATCH
R2  O1  2000            MATCH
```

===============================================================
How do I match values in FVALU and TVALU field from T1 to T2 ?

In above case 3002 and 3291 should match between T1 and T2 tables as well * value should match with 2000. First two column can have join. Also, Notice TVALU sometimes has value and sometimes it is Null

I have tried below query and not working : `SELECT T1.RL, T1.[OR], T1.FVALU, T1.TVALU, IIf(InStr(([T2]![FVALU]),"*")>0,"MATCH",IIf([T1]![FVALU] Between ([T2]![FVALU]) And (IIf([T2]![FVALU] Is Null,[T2]![FVALU],[T2]![FVALU])),"MATCH","DONOTMATCH")) AS MATCHORDOESNOT FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON (T1.[OR] = T2.[OR]) AND (T1.RL = T2.RL);`

Comment: This has nothing to do with `BETWEEN`, which checks for values within a range, as in `value BETWEEN 1 AND 10`. Try using your favorite search engine for *Access JOIN two tables*.

Comment: Simple join is not working since I have to match some value which could be in range and TVALU could be blank on some of the row, that is making complicated against simple join.

Comment: I have tried below query and not working : SELECT T1.RL, T1.OR, T1.FVALU , T1.TVALU , IIf(InStr(([T2]![FVALU ]),"*")>0,"MATCH",IIf([T1]![FVALU ] Between ([T2]![FVALU ]) And (IIf([T2]![TVALU ] Is Null,[T2]![FVALU ],[T2]![TVALU ])),"MATCH","DONOTMATCH")) AS MATCHORDOESNOT, T2.TVALU 
FVALU  T2 INNER JOIN T1 ON (T2.OR = T1.OR) AND (T2.RL = T1.RL);

Comment: Post your expected output in tabular format.

Comment: What do you mean by *last record is not showing*? Also what is the content of the empty columns, is it `NULL` or `''` (empty strings)? Also why there is no value of TVALU in your expected output?

Comment: Result I am expecting my query is only from table T1 which matches values from T2. It has Null values in TVALU in some of the record. Last record in my expected result list is not showing with my query i have posted but it is expected. All Other record is working with my query. All Field Types are Short Text

Comment: Why the first 3291 match and the second one not? Maybe you should explain, editing your original question, and explain with details what is the logic to get the desired output. You are studing 2 tables with a total of 8 records and your desired output is 11 records. That's kind of confusing

Comment: I have fixed what should be. Previously what was showing my query was showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `LEFT` join of the tables and all the conditions in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.*,
       IIF(T2.RL IS NULL, 'DONOTMATCH', 'MATCH') AS MATCHORDOESNOT
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2
ON T2.RL = T1.RL AND T2.[OR] = T1.[OR]
AND (T2.FVALU = T1.FVALU OR (INSTR(T2.FVALU, '*') > 0) OR (T1.FVALU BETWEEN T2.FVALU AND T2.TVALU))
```

Results:

```
RL  OR  FVALU   TVALU   MATCHORDOESNOT
R1  O1  3002            MATCH
R1  O1  3010            DONOTMATCH
R1  O1  3291            MATCH   
R2  O1  2000            MATCH
```